ValueError: A total of 18 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <TextVectorization name=text_vectorization, built=True>:
I am having a problem saving and load models. I have figured out it specifically has to do with the TextVectorization layer but do not know what to do from there.
Here is my code:
class RNNTextClassifier:

    def __init__(self, dataset_name, key):
        VOCAB_SIZE = 5000
        self.dataset_name = dataset_name
        self.key = key
        self.train_dataset, self.val_dataset = self.__load_dataset() 
        self.encoder = self.__build_encoder(VOCAB_SIZE) 
        self.model = self.__build_model(20)

    def save_encoder(self):
        vocab = self.encoder.get_vocabulary()
        vocab_path = f'datastore/model/text/text_classifier_rnn/{self.key}_vocab.txt'
        with open(vocab_path, 'w') as f:
            for word in vocab:
                f.write(f"{word}\n")

    def __load_dataset(self):
        directory = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, f'{self.dataset_name}/train')
        raw_train_ds = tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(  
            directory,
            validation_split=0.2, 
            subset='training',
            seed=42) 
        raw_val_ds = tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
            directory,
            validation_split=0.2,
            subset='validation',
            seed=42)

        train_dataset = raw_train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE) 
        val_dataset = raw_val_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

        return train_dataset, val_dataset

    def __build_encoder(self, vocab_size=1000):
        encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=vocab_size) 
        encoder.adapt(self.train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))
        return encoder

    def __build_model(self, num_classes=20): 
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            self.encoder,
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(  
                input_dim=len(self.encoder.get_vocabulary()),
                output_dim=64, # 128
                # Use masking to handle the variable sequence lengths
                # Not using masking to remove warnings
                mask_zero=False),
           
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)), # 256
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)), # 256
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'), 
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax') 
        ])
        return model

    def train_model(self, num_epochs=1, learning_rate=1e-4):
        model_path = 'datastore/model/text/text_classifier_rnn'
        if not os.path.exists(model_path):
            os.mkdir(model_path)
        best_model_params_path = model_path + '/' + self.key

        self.model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), 
                           optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                           metrics=['accuracy'])

        
        callbacks = [
            tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
                monitor='val_accuracy',
                patience=3,
                restore_best_weights=True
            ),
            tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                'best_model.keras',
                monitor='val_accuracy',
                save_best_only=True
            )
        ]

        start_time = time.time()
        history = self.model.fit(self.train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs,   # 使用 fit 方法开始训练
                                 validation_data=self.val_dataset, validation_steps=30, callbacks=callbacks)
        time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time

        val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
        max_val_acc = max(val_acc) 
        print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
        print(f'Best Val Acc: {max_val_acc:.4f}')
        print(best_model_params_path + '.keras')
        # self.model.save(best_model_params_path + '.keras', include_optimizer=False)
        self.model.save(best_model_params_path + '.keras')
        self.save_encoder()
        # self.model.save_weights(best_model_params_path + '.weights.h5')

        return max_val_acc

class RNNTextClassifierPredictor:

    def __init__(self, exp_key):
        self.exp_key = exp_key
        model_dir = 'datastore/model/text/text_classifier_rnn'
        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, exp_key + '.keras')

        # VOCAB_SIZE = 1000
        # self.encoder = self.__build_encoder(VOCAB_SIZE)
        # self.loaded_model = self.__build_model(1)

        self.loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
        self.encoder = self.__build_encoder()

    def predict(self, text):
        
        encoded_text = self.encoder(tf.constant([text]))  
        result = self.loaded_model(encoded_text)  
        result = tf.sigmoid(result)[0][0]  
        return float(result)  

    def __build_encoder(self, vocab_size=5000):
        encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=vocab_size)
        vocab_path = f'datastore/model/text/text_classifier_rnn/{self.exp_key}_vocab.txt'
       
        if os.path.exists(vocab_path):
            vocab = []
            with open(vocab_path, 'r') as f:
                vocab = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
            encoder.set_vocabulary(vocab)  
        return encoder

Loading the model produces this error:

ValueError: A total of 18 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <TextVectorization name=text_vectorization, built=True>:


List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<TextVectorization name=text_vectorization, built=True>, <StringLookup name=string_lookup, built=False>, <Embedding name=embedding, built=True>, <Bidirectional name=bidirectional, built=True>, <LSTM name=backward_lstm, built=True>, <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>, <LSTM name=forward_lstm, built=
True>, <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>, <Dropout name=dropout, built=True>, <Bidirectional name=bidirectional_1, built=True>, <LSTM name=backward_lstm_1, built=True>, <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>, <LSTM name=forward_lstm_1, built=True>, <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>, <Dropout name=dropout_1, built=True>, <Dense name=dense, built=True>, <Dense name=dense_1, built=True>, <keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x00000178B82152E0>]




I've tried saving the model as .h5 and I've tried saving the model as .keras but neither of them solved the problem, and I've tried saving the encoder separately but that didn't solve it either.

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: I am using tensorflow 2.16.1 and keras 3.3.3

